# Selenium WebDriver: How I can select links randomly?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate login on website and then choosing links randomly from the list of links. After each test run, new link should be selected randomly from list.
I have already automate login:

```
public class Test1{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(path);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get ("http://test.com");

    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    email.sendKeys("brr@gmai.com");


    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    password.sendKeys("1111");
```

Now, I have list of links and need to select them randomly. How could I do it ?

Answer (score 6):

To get list of links use `driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))` and then to select one at random use a random number generator and select the WebElement at the array index.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: fix your `findElement` to be `findElements` then you'll have my vote.  `findElement` will return 1 WebElement.

Comment: I have few links and need to click on them randomly, after each test start e.g. I have logged in, then i see list of link, click on one of them and log off. Then start test again, login and have same list of link and need to click on another. So such all time. How can i click on them ?

Comment: @user3481976 Save the clicked link URLs to a temporary file in the user's profile. Remove the already-clicked-links from the array of "clickable" links, then create the random number generator and pick one at random. Rinse and repeat. Also, typically, when you have these kind of questions you should create a new SO thread and ask your question there since it isn't related to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    Random r = new java.util.Random();
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    WebElement randomElement = links.get(r.nextInt(links.size()));
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would post the exact same thing as I did 10 minutes later. Except with more spoonfeeding.

Comment: Didn't even see your post, I was tabbed in WoW, I use selenium daily :) will +1 yours