# Xpath value of url has 2 intermittent changing elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am automating a scenario wherein I need to click on any random weblink displayed after searching for a term in the search engines. Similar like google search.

Now the problem is that all the weblinks have a similar pattern of XPath in which only 2 html tags get changed intermittently.

Have given the XPath sequence below my code for the reference.

The 4th last div element keeps ascending by 1 which I have handled with random number generator but I am not getting a way how to handle the last tag a because it intermittently changes to either 'a' or a[1].

Below is the code I have used to handle this scenario which fails bcz of the last tag's changed value.

```
for (int iterate=1; iterate<20;)
{
    Random randomNum= new Random();  
    int i = randomNum.nextInt(9) + 1; 
    System.out.println("Random Number generated for iteration " + iterate+ " is: "+i);
    WebElement link2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div[1]/div/a"));
    System.out.println(link2.getText());
    link2.click();
}

//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a
//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a[1]
//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]
//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/a
//*[@id='types']/div[2]/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/a[1]
```

The HTML

```
<main id="types" class="container_12">
    <noscript><div class="error">Website is available.</div></noscript>
    <div class="row layout_3_6_3">
        <section class="grid_3 column ui-sortable-disabled">
        <section class="grid_6 column ui-sortable-disabled">
        <section id="query_debugging" class="widget 
        <section class="widget class">
        <header id="search_results_header" class="query flex space_betwee>
            <div id="search_sorts">
            <div class="widget_inside">
            <div class="result" data-index="0"
            <div class="title"
            <div class="entity-link 
       <a role="menuitem" href="/search/terms1">
```

Comment: Could you provide with `HTML` code for the same or `URL`?

Comment: Added the HTML in the body section as it was too long to paste through comment.

Comment: Could you try just `//a[@role="menuitem"]`?

Comment: But that will only click 19 links in a straight sequence. i am looking for to click on any 19 random result links.

Comment: Please fix the HTML. The elements you posted are incomplete and not properly formatted. It's hard to give an answer with incomplete info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver: How I can select links randomly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767591/selenium-webdriver-how-i-can-select-links-randomly)

Comment: is it that `<a role=...>` you're trying to click? Your xpaths are probably unnecessarily verbose. try the `xpath` suggested by @Andersson or maybe this `//[@id='types']//a[@role='menuitem'][x]` where `x` is the number you want to select.